# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element con java 17

Tags: soap, wsdl, jboss-eap, java-17

Me encuentro migrando a java 17 una aplicación construida en java 8, esta aplicación consume un webservice soap, la interface y estructuras del wsdl fueron construidas con apache cfx. El problema es que al momento de recibir la respuesta, con java 17, me arroja el error,

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element
```

pero si compilo y ejecuto con java 8 no presenta el error.

1. Según entiendo el error se presenta por que en la respuesta nos llega un campo que no estamos esperando.
2. Al migrar a java 17 debo tener algún tema en cuenta.